# Installing Vmware tools on a hypver v guest

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

I'm looking to migrate guests from Hyper-V over to Vmware.
Within the steps, I would like to install vmware tools on the transfer while the guest is running on hyper-V.

As expected, Vmware tools checks the host it's running on and realises it's not running on Esxi.

I've tried removing the rows for "VM_Check" drop the .msi for vmware tools however it has problems when installing as it can't find various files such as comreg.exe.

Any ideas and has anybody been successful with this?

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to do it this way, you're doing it wrong. You can use the VMWare converter to do a V2V migration from Hyper-V over to VMWare and install the tools as part of the conversion process.